# override create method in django rest generics CreateAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views

My views.py of django app is as below,

```
class MemberCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = members.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)

    def create(self, serializer):
        ''' I wanted to do some stuff with serializer.data here '''
        pass
```

Here in the above if I override the create function the return is failing with following error, Even If I don't do any thing and just write pass it is failing ,

```
AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The return should be `instanceof` `Response`.You can return `parent` class response, after your `stuff`

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' I wanted to do some stuff with serializer.data here '''
    return super(MemberCreate, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

or else if you don't want the parent response, then simply return a `Response` instance

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' I wanted to do some stuff with serializer.data here '''
    return Response(status=204)
```

Comment: Here is the DRF default implementation of the `create()`  [https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L12](link) It may help if you need it.

Answer (score 6):

Your view should return a `Response` object, as said in your `AssertionError` stacktrace.

In your case, you can try to return an empty `Response` in order to test your view and your `serializer.data`

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class MemberCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = members.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(...)
        data = serializer.data

        # ...

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Typically, you want to return your `serializer.validated_data` in the end, so this line probably will look like this:

```
return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```